# Why is there no Video audio for Android?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-av

I am rendering a list of videos. The videos work great on iOS but on Android, the audio doesn’t work. Here’s my code

```
<Video
    key={recommendationImage.id}
    style={styles.recommendationImage}
    source={{ uri: recommendationImage.img_url }}
    shouldPlay={this.state.videoIsPlaying}
    isLooping={true}
    useNativeControls={true}
    isMuted={this.state.videoIsMuted}
    resizeMode="cover"
/>
```

This is my state:

```
this.state = {
   isLiked: false,
   videoIsPlaying: true,
   videoIsMuted: true,
};
```

I am using `expo-av` for my Video component. The is my version: `"expo-av": "~8.2.1"`

It works perfect on iOS but not on Android. Is this an expo issue?

Comment: why do you expect audio if "videoIsMuted: true"?

Comment: @Henry ah yes. It’s because iOS has their media player with the audio icon. Thanks.